# I want to update a column with a new value of date different in days

Tags: python, mysql, sql

there's my request :

```
SELECT id, score1, score2, date_calcul, valeur, DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_calcul) 
FROM customer_info
```

how to update the valeur column to have values of DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_calcul)

Comment: You would have to do an UPDATE query! I assume you want to actually apply an update to the `valeur` column on the table?

Comment: Yes this what i want

Answer (score 0):

You need to run an **UPDATE**

```
UPDATE customer_info
SET valeur = DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_calcul) ;
```

you may want to add a condition, for example

```
WHERE id > 100;
```

**NB** If you are going to update this column every day to keep it up to date you would do better to create a **VIEW**.

Comment: What every row in the table ??

Comment: sounds like it!

Comment: UPDATE customer_info AS c 
SET valeur = DATEDIFF(NOW(), c.date_calcul) ;

Comment: i fixed it guys